# Is it possible to adjust the bar pin size of plotly bar chart?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, plotly

I am using plotly express library

my bar chart is :

```
fig = px.bar(abc_df, x=abc_df['xdata'],y = abc_df['ydata'],width= 20,title="Chart Title" )

fig.update_layout(
    title_font_family="Times New Roman",
    title_font_color="red",
    autosize=True,
    width=1800,
    height=600,) 
fig.show()
```

[plotly express bar cookbook](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.bar)

Which parameters do i need to adjust to change this?
thanks

Comment: What do you mean by the pin size?

Comment: thanks .I solved the problem by using fig.update_traces(width=40000000, selector=dict(type='bar'))
just wonder why the width need so large as i test many many times from 0.x to <100 still have didn't make any change